# How to compile and work samtools with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, samtools

I need some help to resolve this problem. I got an error when I compiled Samtools under Cygwin (windows 8 64 bit).

I got the following message:

ADMIN@USER ~/samtools-0.1.19

```
$ make    
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMIN/Cygwin/home/samtools-0.1.19'    
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMIN/Cygwin/home/samtools-0.1.19'    
gcc -c -g -Wall -O2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_USE_KNETFILE -D_CURSES_LIB=1 -DBGZF_CACHE -I. bgzf.c -o bgzf.o    
In file included from bgzf.c:32:0:    
bgzf.h:33:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory    
#include <zlib.h>        
^         
compilation terminated.    
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'bgzf.o' failed    
make[2]: *** [bgzf.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMIN/Cygwin/home/samtools-0.1.19'
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'lib-recur' failed
make[1]: *** [lib-recur] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/ADMIN/Cygwin/home/samtools-0.1.19'
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'all-recur' failed
make: *** [all-recur] Error 1
```

please tell me what went wrong and how I need to correct it. I tried to make a few changes to the Makefile like 
changed the -D_CURSES_LIB=1 to -D_CURSES_LIB=0
changed "LIBCURSES=      -lcurses # -lXCurses" to "LIBCURSES=     #
-lcurses # -lXCurse

the error message still continues, please help..

Comment: Looks like you have to install the development package for zlib (just having the runtime one from Base is not enough).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and solved it with the following steps:

Start the Cygwin Installer, in the "Select Package" page, search and install gcc-g++, gdb, make, libncurses, zlib, zlib-devel.

Download and extract samtools.

Append `-Dexpl=exp -Dlogl=log` to Makefile's default `DFLAGS` line, such as:

```
DFLAGS= -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_CURSES_LIB=1 -Dexpl=exp -Dlogl=log
```

Run `make clean` to clean up previous build attempts.

Then run `make`.

Copy samtools.exe and misc folder to the system path. Or for samtools version 1.0 or later, run `make install`.

Please note: samtools is now in [version 1.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/samtools/). You should try it first.

More information is on [my blog](http://azaleasays.com/2014/09/29/install-samtools-in-cygwin/).

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working.  I'm  getting a first error saying `bgzf.c:630:8:warning: variable 'count' set but not used  [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`
At the end it says `make: *** [Makefile:25: all-recur] Error 1`